# How to get the HWND of the next window that will be active when you minimize the foreground window?

Tags: c++, winapi

Scenario: there's windows `X` in the foreground, when you minimize it, it will bring windows `Y` to the front or the desktop.

What `WINAPI` i could use to get the `HWND` of `Y`, before minimizing `X`?

I tried this:

```cpp
HWND hWndnext = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
```

but it didn't return the `HWND` i was looking for.

I'm trying to set my window transparent upon trying to minimize, but not letting it be minimized, and after it gets transparent, activate/focus whatever would be the next window case it really was minimized, and upon clicking on it again restore the transparency to default.

My second attempt was:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
{
    if (wParam == SC_MINIMIZE) {

        DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

        BYTE alpha = GetWindowAlpha(hWnd) ? 0 : 255;

        // Update the window transparency.
        DWORD exstyle = GetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, alpha, LWA_ALPHA);

        // Attempt to restore the window without activating it.
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
        return 0;

    }
    break;
}
```

But it still ain't focusing the next window into the taskbar.

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual problem X that you are trying to solve with Y posted in the question?

Comment: There is no such API. Minimize that window, then call GetForegroundWindow() to see what's next.

Answer (score 0):

The [`EnumWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) API allows to get the list of windows by Z-order.

Comment: That's only half of an answer. The other part would be how the system selects the next window eligible to become the foreground window when the current foreground window get minimized.

Comment: @IInspectable is there any reason to believe it's *not* by Z-order?

Comment: @mar The Z-order is very likely part of that selection algorithm. It's equally probable that the Z-order isn't *all* that's considered. What, if the next window in Z-order is disabled, for example?